# Inputing postcode when geocoding with MMQGIS Web Service

Tags: qgis, geocoding, postal-code, mmqgis

I frequently use MMQGIS Plugin (*Geocode >> Geocode CSV with Google / OpenStreetMap*) in QGIS 2.18.10 (64bit) to geocode adresses from a CSV file. In particular for Germany, but I would imagine this issue cuts across country borders.

My CSV file contains a seperate column with postcode information, but there is no field to input it in the dialog window. I need to use the postcode information for geocoding. Should I concatenate it with another field like *City* (for example - *10117 Berlin*)? Does anyone know where to input the postcode?

[image: Dialog window for MMQGIS Geocoding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field in Excel before bringing into QGIS.

Address & " " & Postcode

Or perhaps:

City & " " & Postcode

Comment: Thanks Heikki, I know I can do that, but to which field should I feed it?

Comment: I think it is just creating a single string to pass to the geocoder. So if you usually type an address as . 1 Main St, 10117, Berlin, Germany, I would do Postcode & " " & City.